# How can I install Zope on Ubuntu 10.04 with Python 2.6.5?

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, python, zope

I tried to install Zope on Ubuntu server 10.04:

```
mnk@srv:~/zope-plone/Zope-3.4.0$ ./configure --prefix=/opt/zope-3.4.0

Configuring Zope installation

Testing for an acceptable Python interpreter...

Python version 2.6.5 found at /usr/bin/python
Python version 2.6.5 found at /usr/bin/python2

No suitable Python version found. You should install
Python version 2.4.3 before continuing. Versions
2.4.7 2.4.6 2.4.5 2.4.4 2.4.2 2.4.1 also work, but not as optimally.
```

So can I install Zope with my Python 2.6.5 or I need to install 2.4.3 version?
And if I install this version of Python will I have some problems with my system or other python applications?

Answer (score 0):

I installed old Python version:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential gcc
wget http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.4.6/Python-2.4.6.tgz
tar -xvzf Python-2.4.6.tgz
cd Python-2.4.6
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/python2.4.6
make
make test
sudo make install
sudo ln -s /usr/local/python2.4.6/bin/python /usr/bin/python2.4.6
```

Then I change Zope configure file to add this Python version as acceptiable.

```
vim Zope-3.4.0/configure

EXENAMES="python python2 python2.4" => EXENAMES="python python2 python2.4.6"
```

And only after this changes I installed Zope. But I still have some problems with Zope start. So I don`t sure that I can launch it.